# Attribute is not updating using LINQ TO XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I load an xml file into an Xelement.  I then look for an an element named R via:

```
XElement elem = xmlTemplate.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "R").FirstOrDefault();
```

I then search for the attributes EF and EX via:

```
elem.Attribute("EF").SetValue(txtEffective.Text);
elem.Attribute("EX").SetValue(txtExpire.Text);
```

but when I call xTemplate.Save(...), it does not save the udpated attributes.  I have also tried:

```
elem.Attribute("EF").Value = txtEffective.Text;
elem.Attribute("EX").Value = txtExpire.Text;
```

Comment: Could you please include your XML file? Your code should work, and you can check it with "string xml = xmlTemplate.ToString();" to see if your XElement updated or not. Maybe you'll have problems with save ....

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, but not sure how to avoid it.  When I load the XML, I am loading the two attributes in two text boxes on the form.  When I change the values in the text box to update the attributes, it is updating the xml with the original values in the text box and not new ones.  I wonder if this has to do with the fact that the text boxes are loaded on page load and when I click the button, it actually loads the xml again and overwrites my new values with the original values.  After I did not load the values in the text box, the save worked fine.